# FFMPEG - Merging .wav files with acrossfade and getting audio crackling

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, merge, transcode

i'm merging two audio files into 1 with a acrossfade filter.

Here is my acrossfade filter config: `acrossfade=d=10:o=1:curve1=cbr:curve2=cbr`;

The merge is working well, but for some files it results in a intense audio crackling when both of files are playing togheter.

Thanks for any help.

I'm using fluent-ffmpeg, but the commando line should be it:

`ffmpeg -i file1.wav file2.wav -filter_complex "acrossfade=d=10:o=1:curve1=log:curve2=log"`

The log provided by fluent-ffmpeg is:
[SEE THE LOG HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGTvs.png)

PS: this issue only occurs when one or both files are .wav

Comment: Show all of your command and provide the complete log.

Comment: I did it in the main question

Comment: Unable to duplicate the issue. 1) Your ffmpeg is old. [Download a recent ffmpeg](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/) (git version, not release version) and try again. 2) If it still does not work provide links to the input files.

Comment: I used a recent git version but the problem remains. Follows the link for the input files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/102IuXp4lwNE2K7FBcbxdcC1veda-MaO2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sounds normal to me with the files you provided. I assumed your command is `ffmpeg -i FILE-1.mp3 -i FILE-2.mp3 -filter_complex "acrossfade=d=10:o=1:curve1=log:curve2=log" output.wav`

Comment: so could it be a issue with fluent-ffmpeg?

Comment: I noticed that the crackling only occurs when the inputs are .wav, any idea about how to fix this without converting all the files, since it increase the proccess time and i'm concatenating a large number of files?

Comment: in real-time audio processing, crackling is often a buffer issue; I notice there is a FIFO mechanism for ffmpeg that decouples muxing and encoding to help with latency issues. I am no expert here, but the log PNG may implicate transcoding as the streams are mismatched bitrate and sample rate. I also notice that the "speed" item in the output log says the output is 1,200x (if I read `1.2e+03x` correctly). This may be a trivial error or it might confuse a playback device...I have seen naive playback devices pop and crackle when playing audio "in slow motion"( google: "ffmpeg fifo pseudo-muxer" )

Comment: As you can see here: https://prnt.sc/193omyw, even if i use two files with the same sample and bitrate, i still getting the issue.  :(

Comment: If you think it is a bug then you can [report it](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/), but you must: 1) use the most recent ffmpeg you can (from git, not a release) 2) Show **all** of your command 3) Show the **complete** log 4) Copy and paste the log text. **Do not** make a screenshot of text 5) Provide a link to the inputs file. If you do not follow these steps your bug report may get ignored because there are so many reports.